# Tip the return of the api Lucid ORM

Tags: javascript, orm, adonis.js

My query returns the correct data from the site, I would like to change the return format but I am not getting it.

My query

```
const message = Message.query().where('group_id', group_id).limit(limit).orderBy('id', 'desc')
  .with('user').fetch()
```

This is the current result

```
[{
  "id": 39,
  "user_id": 11,
  "group_id": 43,
  "message": "asdfasdfsadf",
  "created_at": "2018-08-20 15:51:39",
  "updated_at": "2018-08-20 15:51:39",
  "user": {
    "id": 11,
    "username": "a",
    "email": "a",
    "password": "$2a$10$f3fMuqVxV4UZqAMX4xIXiukLc1EelZjKhG8jm.CSmTAWyyZYLmR66",
    "created_at": "2018-08-18 08:46:46",
    "updated_at": "2018-08-18 08:46:46"
  }
}]
```

I would like the following returned

```
[{
  "_id": 39,
  "user_id": 11,
  "group_id": 43,
  "text": "asdfasdfsadf",
  "createdAt": "2018-08-20 15:51:39",
  "user": {
    "_id": 11,
    "name": "a",
  }
}]
```

If I put the `.select ([])` at the beginning of the query it does not load the user.

See that I am making the following changes in the fields

message for text
id for _id
and removing some

Comment: What is the problem here? Just create a new Object that has the elements you need in them and return it

Comment: I do not like to popular an object, since the same comes from the bank. Being an ORM should give you the option to rename the fields, right?

Comment: I tried this: ```const message = Message.query (). Select (['id as _id',
     'message as text',
     'created_at as createdAt']). where ('group_id', group_id) .limit (limit) .orderBy ('id', 'desc')
     .with ('user', (sel) => {
       sel.select ('*') from ('users')
     }) fetch ()``` did not work

Comment: Two ways: 1. Config hidden field in `User` model. 2. use `.with('user', query => {query.select('id', 'name')})`

Answer (score 0):

Saying to your model which columns should be returned would fit to you?

Add this to your User model:

```
  public static get columns() {
    return ["_id", "name"];
  }
```